# Преобразование кортежа из типа str в int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я генерирую кортеж `key=(0, 2, 4, 1, 3)`Затем передаю его от сервера

Отправка сервером:

```
conn.send((str)(key).encode('utf-8'))
```

Принятие клиентом:

```
data2 = sock.recv(16384)  
str2 = (data2.decode('utf-8'))
```

В результате чего у меня key становится str. Как вернуть его обратно в int?

Comment: `tuple(map(int, str2[1:-1].split(", ")))`. Но это извращение какое-то. Лучше бы воспользовались модулем `pickle` для сериализации любых **built-in** типов в `bytes`.

Comment: А пример не приведете с pickle ?

Comment: `b = pickle.dumps(key); print(pickle.loads(b)`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(str2)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052160/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то:

```
x = 'your key'
str1 = str(x) #ключ в string формате
int1 = int(x) #ключ в integer формате
```

Если не переводит, то скорее всего есть символы в переменной, которые не входят в диапозон понимания "int"

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли суть вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался сам. Нужно было убрать скобки и преобразовать каждый элемент