# Передача списка Python через сокет

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, сериализация

Я передаю от сервера к клиенту Список

```
['c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

Передача сервером:

```
conn.send((str)(key).encode('utf-8'))
```

Принятие клиентом:

```
data2 = sock.recv(16384)  
str2 = (data2.decode('utf-8'))
```

Дело в том что список приходит как `"['c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'b']"`
Как убрать эти `" "`?

Comment: Получается что str в str

Comment: Лучше передавайте как `json` и парсите через json. Либо сериализуйте через pickle

Comment: @gil9red так мне нужно не через файлы передавать

Comment: json это формат в виде строки, сериализуйте через json получите строку в формате json

Comment: Кст, а зачем вам эти лишние круглые скобки? `(str)(key).` -> `str(key).` и `str2 = (data2.decode('utf-8'))` -> `str2 = data2.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам на самом деле нужно передавать список, а не кавычки убрать.

Поэтому, не используйте костыли, и сериализуйте данные в `json`:

```
import json
...
key = ['c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'b']
conn.send(json.dumps(key).encode('utf-8'))
```

и

```
import json
...
data2 = sock.recv(16384)
key = json.loads(data2, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Это то что мне нужно, Спасибо